# How to open Emacs like in Linux Terminal

Tags: terminal, emacs

I just got a Macbook (my first one!) and want to know how to configure Emacs to run in the same way it runs in Linux. That is, if I type "emacs foo.c &" in the Terminal, I want to either open either a new or existing file called foo.c in a separate Emacs window, NOT in the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

If the emacs you are running in Linux creates a new window then you are running it as an X11 application (a GUI application).  Normally emacs on Linux and other systems just runs in the terminal you have open (as a console application).

The version of emacs that ships with OS X is compiled just to run in a terminal. To replicate running in a new window you need another version of emacs. I would use [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) which is an emacs modified to act like a normal OSX Cocoa app. The standard [GNU emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has a Cocoa app version which defaults to be more similar to behaviour on other platforms and is available in a binary version [here](http://emacsformacosx.com).

You can also get X11 versions as well.  Here is an exhaustive list of the available types of [emacs for OS X](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS).

Comment: The can also get that standard emacs from [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `brew install emacs`.

Comment: Most package managers do provide emacs eg macports fink conda. Also several places to download from. Don't make a decision on package managers on just emacs.